# How do I can add a box show the image I click and eraser

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

how can I do something like this box show in all activity in my app, and when I press any image in my app the image show in this box, any one can help me with this

[the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKVGH.png)

Comment: please add your code so people can help you

Comment: sorry I don't have a code yet, I just want to know what the idea to do like the image that I added as attachment, I have no idea how to do it

Comment: check out my answer and if you need basic tutorials check these links: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-hello-world-example/
http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-activity-from-one-screen-to-another-screen/

Answer (score 0):

well in android xml layout there is no box shadow attribute, thats why we use border or stroke, or you can create 2 boxes on top of each other with a little displacement to create shadow look, using layer-list this is boxshadow.xml drawable xml file, saved in res/drawable folder :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item  >
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="10dip" />
            <gradient
                android:angle="0"
                android:endColor="#cccccc"
                android:startColor="#4c4c4c" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:left="3dp" android:top="3dp" >
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="10dip" />
            <gradient
                android:angle="270"
                android:centerColor="#f8d79b"
                android:centerY="0.5"
                android:endColor="#f8d79b"
                android:startColor="#f8d79b" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

this is just an example and here is the result for this shape:

[image]

I used the xml file as background for a button in the activitylayout.xml like this:

```
 <Button
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Back"
        android:id="@+id/button_back"
        android:background="@drawable/boxshadow" />
```

of course you can use the same boxshadow.xml as a background for any other element such as TextView, EditText or ImageView.